# Google Closure Annotating won't tell me I'm wrong

Tags: javascript, compiler-warnings, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I'm trying out Google Closure, specifically the annotating stuff to enforce type safety. To test I did something wrong, though the compiler won't tell me that it is...

Here's the code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 * A card.
 * @constructor
 * @param {String} cardName The exact name of the card
 * @param {Kinetic.Layer} layer The layer for the card
 */
function CardObject(cardName, layer)
{
    /** @type {Number} */
    var number = cardName;
}
```

So, I have a variable `number` which I say is a `Number`, and I try to assign a string to it. This shouldn't be possible, right? Though the compiler won't tell me that...

Why won't it tell me that's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closure Compiler uses [warning levels](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref#warn) to determine which checks are enabled during the compilation process. The three warning levels are:

- QUIET
- DEFAULT
- VERBOSE

For example, using compilation level `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`, you will still get type-check warnings with the warning level set to `VERBOSE`.

```js
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @warning_level VERBOSE
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 * A card.
 * @constructor
 * @param {String} cardName The exact name of the card
 * @param {Kinetic.Layer} layer The layer for the card
 */
function CardObject(cardName, layer)
{
    /** @type {Number} */
    var number = cardName;
}
```

**Output**

```
Number of warnings: 2

JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation. Unknown type Kinetic.Layer at line 5
character 10  
* @param {Kinetic.Layer} layer The layer for the card
          ^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: initializing variable
found   : (String|null|undefined)
required: (Number|null) at line 10 character 13
var number = cardName;
             ^
```

To understand exactly which checks are associated with each warning level, here is the relevant code from WarningLevels.java.

## QUIET

```java
/**
 * Silence all non-essential warnings.
 */
private static void silenceAllWarnings(CompilerOptions options) {
  // Just use a ShowByPath warnings guard, so that we don't have
  // to maintain a separate class of warnings guards for silencing warnings.
  options.addWarningsGuard(
      new ShowByPathWarningsGuard(
          "the_longest_path_that_cannot_be_expressed_as_a_string"));

  // Allow passes that aren't going to report anything to be skipped.

  options.checkRequires = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.checkProvides = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.checkMissingGetCssNameLevel = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.aggressiveVarCheck = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.checkTypes = false;
  options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.CHECK_TYPES, CheckLevel.OFF);
  options.checkUnreachableCode = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.checkMissingReturn = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.ACCESS_CONTROLS, CheckLevel.OFF);
  options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.CONST, CheckLevel.OFF);
  options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.CONSTANT_PROPERTY, CheckLevel.OFF);
  options.checkGlobalNamesLevel = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.checkSuspiciousCode = false;
  options.checkGlobalThisLevel = CheckLevel.OFF;
  options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.GLOBAL_THIS, CheckLevel.OFF);
  options.setWarningLevel(DiagnosticGroups.ES5_STRICT, CheckLevel.OFF);
  options.checkCaja = false;
}
```

## DEFAULT

```
/**
 * Add the default checking pass to the compilation options.
 * @param options The CompilerOptions object to set the options on.
 */
private static void addDefaultWarnings(CompilerOptions options) {
  options.checkSuspiciousCode = true;
  options.checkUnreachableCode = CheckLevel.WARNING;
  options.checkControlStructures = true;
}
```

## VERBOSE

```
/**
 * Add all the check pass that are possibly relevant to a non-googler.
 * @param options The CompilerOptions object to set the options on.
 */
private static void addVerboseWarnings(CompilerOptions options) {
  addDefaultWarnings(options);

  // checkSuspiciousCode needs to be enabled for CheckGlobalThis to get run.
  options.checkSuspiciousCode = true;
  options.checkGlobalThisLevel = CheckLevel.WARNING;
  options.checkSymbols = true;
  options.checkMissingReturn = CheckLevel.WARNING;

  // checkTypes has the side-effect of asserting that the
  // correct number of arguments are passed to a function.
  // Because the CodingConvention used with the web service does not provide a
  // way for optional arguments to be specified, these warnings may result in
  // false positives.
  options.checkTypes = true;
  options.checkGlobalNamesLevel = CheckLevel.WARNING;
  options.aggressiveVarCheck = CheckLevel.WARNING;
  options.setWarningLevel(
      DiagnosticGroups.MISSING_PROPERTIES, CheckLevel.WARNING);
  options.setWarningLevel(
      DiagnosticGroups.DEPRECATED, CheckLevel.WARNING);
}
```

Notice that `options.checkTypes = true;` is only set for the VERBOSE warning level. As [Speransky Danil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550807/speransky-danil) pointed out, type checking is also enabled when using compilation level `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

In addition, classes of warnings may be controlled individually with the Closure Compiler application (jar file) using compiler flags:

- --jscomp_off
- --jscomp_warning
- --jscomp_error

The warning classes that may be specified are as follows:

- accessControls
- ambiguousFunctionDecl
- checkRegExp
- checkTypes
- checkVars
- const
- constantProperty
- deprecated
- duplicateMessage
- es5Strict
- externsValidation
- fileoverviewTags
- globalThis
- internetExplorerChecks
- invalidCasts
- missingProperties
- nonStandardJsDocs
- strictModuleDepCheck
- typeInvalidation
- undefinedNames
- undefinedVars
- unknownDefines
- uselessCode
- visibility

For example, type checking warnings could be enabled individually:

```
--jscomp_warning=checkTypes
```

Comment: Ok, this is an incredible answers. Thanks, I learned a lot, and now I can use simple optimization with type checking :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just select advanced optimization mode:

```
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
```

Then for this code for example:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
* @param {String} str
*/
function func(str) {
  /** @type {Number} */
  var num = str;
}
```

There will be warning:

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: initializing variable
found   : (String|null)
required: (Number|null) at line 6 character 10
var num = str;
```

I think you know, but if not, you can play with it online here: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Hmm, you are totally right. Is there a reason why it doesn't do the checking in the simple optimization? Since advanced is a little too agressive for my taste. I have multiple js files and the advanced changes names of functions apparently (only just started using the closure stuff, so might be wrong)

Comment: I just tried compiling my Card.js (which contains my card object stuff) with the advanced optimization, and it compiles it away. I get an empty file, I assume because it can't find that it's used anywhere. But it is used, only in an other js file...

Comment: I'm using the jar file, called from within Notepad++: "java -jar "C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\Google Closure\compiler.jar" --js "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" --js_output_file "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).compiled" --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS"